# Display list as ring buffer

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

So here is what I am trying to do:

Referring to Frame #2 in my professionally designed diagram, if I have a list that has more than four items, the list should become a sort of ring buffer/rolodex where the whole list scrolls in a loop, the top and bottom fading out in a gradient.

If anyone could shed some light on how to go about doing this, I'd be very appreciative.

Note: Using SVG is not a problem if it is required.

Here is the current state of affairs: http://excessive.io/sao/

Edit: Here is a purely SVG example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/73045haj6b7vpwj/menu.svg

Comment: Can you post any of the related code for this question?

Comment: I posted a link in the OP. There is no current code for the ring buffer, as I can't for the life of me figure out how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this and found it beneficial to treat it as a looping slideshow. There are all kinds of examples on how to do one of them online. As far as the fading there are different ways to do that. easiest would be png gradients positioned absolutely in the rolodex container.